# Как на C# построить такой curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer nFRJxzCD8OOUr7hzBwbr06D76zAT" "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"

Tags: c#, curl, get

Пытаюсь построить запрос на C#. POST запрос получилось сделать для получения Access Token, по аналогии пытался GET запрос сделать. Но вылетает либо ошибка 401, либо 404. Поскажите, что не так делаю.

```cs
string ACCESS_TOKEN = richTextBox4.Text;
string data = $"Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(data + $" https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs");
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `WebRequest` устарел
2. Вы пытаетесь засунуть HTTP заголовок в URL запроса, само собой у вас ничего не получается.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string text = await GetApiRequestAsync("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs");
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetApiRequestAsync(string url)
{
    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN);
    using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // бросает исплючение при ответе сервера с кодом ошибки
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Если вы используете старый .NET Framework, то синтаксис C# 8 у вас не прокатит, тогда метод отправки запроса будет выглядеть так:

```
private async Task<string> GetApiRequestAsync(string url)
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN);
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // бросает исплючение при ответе сервера с кодом ошибки
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```